# NodeJS function not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I am calling a function to build a specially formatted string (x2) from an array of strings (x).

Code:

```
http.createServer(function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    ...
    function test(x){
        var x2="";
        x2.concat(x);
        return x2;
    }
    ...
    var x = "abcd";
    console.log(test(x));
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

The result is that the function doesn't get called. I've tried placing a `console.log("...")` inside and it doesn't show either. Everything else in the project works fine.

I'm completely new to JS/NodeJS so it might be something trivial I'm missing.

Comment: And this code does what?  Produces an error?  Times out? Sets the atmosphere on fire?  We need a bit more information.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll add the result to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is to return the result of `concat` because `concat` doesn't affect the either String and instead returns a new String.

`return x2.concat(x);`

See this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) for information about `concat`.

Also, I'd take a look at the "Performance" section of that link. It says:

> It is strongly recommended that assignment operators (+, +=) are used instead of the concat() method.

Comment: That was it. I had a hunch it could be something that trivial, thank you very much for pointing it out! I too prefer using "+", but my formatted string has ~250 lines and certain parts are numerical so I often get NaN because of that. I couldn't find a better solution.Thank you for taking your time to answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I'm not sure if you are getting an error or what exactly is happening. From looking at your code everything looks like it should work okay, but I'm guessing your request never finishes. Try adding

```
res.end('okay');
```

to your handler function. This will close the request and send back 'okay' as 'text/html'.